# my program opens and closes and finally opens, why and how to fix it? https://github.com/akparovag/project.git

Tags: java, android

It seems to me that the HomeFragment class is a problem

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
    private GridView catView;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        catView = view.findViewById(R.id.cat_Grid);

        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(DbQuery.g_catList);
        catView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you want people to answer this, you should explain more about what you have done and what the exact problem is.

See http://sscce.org/ for more advice.